# Bootstrapping using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I am implementing a bootstrap procedure using `Rcpp` and seem to have hit a performance bottleneck (?). Basically, I am creating a boot matrix using `RcppArmadillo`, calling the `fit_power_law` function from `igraph` and estimating the power law coefficient. The code is as follows:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]] 

double alphaPLFit(const arma::vec& x) {

  Environment igraph("package:igraph");
  Function fit_power_law = igraph["fit_power_law"];

  List p = fit_power_law(Named("x", x));

  return p["alpha"];
}

arma::mat bootstraps(const arma::vec& x, int times) {
  arma::mat bootMatrix;

  for (int t = 0; t < times; ++t) {
    arma::vec resample = RcppArmadillo::sample(x, x.n_elem, true);
    bootMatrix.insert_cols(t, resample);
  }

  return bootMatrix;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec bootAlphaPLFit(const arma::vec& x, int times) {
  arma::mat bootMatrix = bootstraps(x, times);
  arma::vec alphas(times);

  for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    double alpha = alphaPLFit(bootMatrix.col(i));
    alphas[i] = alpha;
  }

  return alphas;
}

/***R
library(igraph)
sampleData <- degree(sample_pa(n = 1e5, m = 3, directed = FALSE))
system.time(bootAlphaPLFit(sampleData, 500))

*/
```

This takes about a minute to run on my computer. As a comparison, the `boot` function from the `boot` package takes about 30 seconds, with a custom statistic that calls `igraph::fit_power_law` and extracts alpha.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: You are calling an R function: `Function fit_power_law = igraph["fit_power_law"];` That will be at the speed of R, not C++.

Comment: You are right, I was wondering if the message passing overhead between arma and R is the reason for this slowdown compared to a normal R script that uses the `boot` package instead. Alas, Rcpp is no R-to-Cpp converter :)

Comment: Psst, there is a nice snippet in the new [Rcpp introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) that shows bootstrapping with _Rcpp_.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a nice example. In real-life, bootstrapping almost always requires calling R functions from other packages (as illustrated in my question). Thinking out loud, there should be a way for package users like me to hook our own Rcpp code into Rcpp functions used by packages  (My current minimal knowledge limits me to think if this is indeed possible)